# Singleton instance vs new instance vs const var in Typescript for multi language Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript

I implemented this simple approach of a multi language angular app and not the default Angular i18n internalization because it seems to me a little bit complicated.

So we have this interface:

```
    export interface Messages {

      welcome: string;
      msg1: string;
      msg2: string;

      dynamic: (user: string) => string;

    }
```

and then we use this interface like this:

A class

```
    import {Messages} from './messages';

    export class MessagesEN implements Messages {

      welcome = 'welcome';
      msg1 = 'message one';
      msg2 = 'hello second!';

      dynamic = (user) => `hi ${user}`;
    }
```

A singleton

```
    import {Messages} from './messages';

    export class MessagesGR implements Messages {

      private static _INSTANCE: Messages;

      private constructor() {
      }

      static get INSTANCE(): Messages {
        return this._INSTANCE || (this._INSTANCE = new this());
      }

      welcome = 'καλως ηρθατε';
      msg1 = 'μηνυμα ενα';
      msg2 = 'ειμαι ο δευτερος!';

      dynamic = (user) => `γεια σου ${user}`;
    }
```

A const var

```
    import {Messages} from './messages';

    export const ALB: Messages = {

      welcome: 'mire se erdhet',
      msg1: 'mesazhi nje',
      msg2: 'jam e duta',

      dynamic: (user) => `si jeni ${user}`
    };
```

then we have a MessagesService:

```
    import {Messages} from './messages';
    import {MessagesGR} from './messages.gr';
    import {ALB} from './messages.alb';
    import {MessagesEN} from './messages.en';

    export class MessagesService {

      messages: Messages;

      constructor() {
        const lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
        this.init(lang);
      }

      public init(lang: string) {
        switch (lang) {
          case 'alb':
            this.messages = ALB;
            break;
          case 'en':
            this.messages = new MessagesEN();
            break;
          case 'gr':
          default:
            this.messages = MessagesGR.INSTANCE;
        }
      }
    }
```

and then in the components html we use the MessagesService.
Everything works fine either way.

My question is which way is better (performance and memory wise)

1. const var (ALB)
2. class (EN)
3. singleton (GR)

Answer (score 0):

Angular injector can naturally produce singletons. There's no need for special 'singleton' class in Angular.

There's no reason to use a class if it isn't supposed to be extended or reinstantiated - especially if it holds only data and no logic.

A constant is exhaustive solution here. Additionally, it can be made an Angular service in order to make use of DI and provide additional possibilities for extensibility.

Comment: Angular injector will initialize all classes eagerly, I don't think this is the best way for this, because there is a big chance the user will not change the language so lazy initialization its a better approach.

Comment: It will initialize them lazily, as soon as they are injected. If you want to avoid their initialization, retrieve an instance with `injector.get(messageServiceToken)` instead of injecting it in constructor. This can be considered premature optimization. You still need to have all languages defined within an app.